# PowerBI DAX: Sum over a range in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a pretty simple table containing one field which is a boolean (True/False) and another which is a date.
for example:

```
False 10/1/2019 
True 10/12/2019
True 10/13/2019
False 11/1/2019
```

I want to create a 3rd column that will show me how many True values I saw up to this date (the table is sorted by date), so in this case this would be:

```
False 10/1/2019 0
True 10/12/2019 1
True 10/13/2019 2 
False 11/1/2019 2
```

What is the best way to this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You can try this calculated column:

```
Count = 
    var ThisDate = 'Table'[Date]
    var vCount = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Date] <= ThisDate && 'Table'[Boolean] = TRUE))
return
    vCount + 0
```

I needed to add zero at the end to display a number instead of a blank value, as it is in the case of the first row. The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!
 I've tried something similar but both failed because I can not assign 

Var ThisDate = 'Table'[Date] 

(I get this error : A single value for column 'Date' in table 'Table' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: Glad to be of help. The error means that you are trying to create a measure. Make sure to select a table and use "New column" option, in order to add a new column to your data table.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much, I though I had to use measure if I wanted to add custom logic. this solved it :)

Comment: There's actually a thin line between measure and a column :-) here's one of the best articles to check out the difference -> [link](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/). Good luck!